# SQL join statement, issues

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to SQL and thus not able to compose the `JOIN` statement for this query.

I've the following two tables

```
Teachers

+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Courses

+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teacher_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to write a Java `PreparedStatement` string to query that `given a course id the details of the teacher for the course is returned`. Can someone help writing this.

Comment: This is homework question, but does not conform to [the SO policies for such questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). You have not posted any evidence of a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "how do I do this?" type of question, with no evidence of an attempt at a solution from the poster.  The question can be solved easily with a little research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    courses c
JOIN    teachers t
ON      t.id = c.teacher_id
WHERE   c.id = ?
```

Comment: So to make this a JDBC PreparedStatement should I just use ? for myid?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN Teachers
ON Courses.teacher_id=Teachers.id;
```